# Use of Regex based partial matches to select a subdataframe of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a Pandas dataframe that has two columns, one (column "Process Parameter") that has strings, and the other (column "Value") that has corresponding float values. I need to filter out a subdataframe that partially matches a set of keys in Column 'Process Parameter' and extracts both columns of the dataframe that matches these keys

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Process Parameter' : ['Temperature', 'System Clk', 'Core Clk', 'Bilinear Coeff', 'Prec Coeff', 'Yield'], 'Value' : [1.2,2.0,3.0, 5.1, 6.2, 7.4]})

keys =['Clk', 'Coeff']
```

I should get an output

df_filtered as

```
Process Parameter    Value
System Clk            3.0
Core Clk              2.0
Bilinear Coeff        5.1
Prec Coeff            6.2
```

I tried several messy ways like converting the dataframe to lists and then using 
re.search(), map, str.contains() etc. Anyone who has a very efficient solution please let me know

Thanks & Regards,
santosh

Comment: All `keys` are only one word or is possible multiple words like `keys =['Clk aa', 'Coeff b']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can use `numpy.core.defchararray.find`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

p = df['Process Parameter'].values.astype(str)
df[(find(p[:, None], keys) >= 0).any(1)]

  Process Parameter  Value
1        System Clk    2.0
2          Core Clk    3.0
3    Bilinear Coeff    5.1
4        Prec Coeff    6.2
```

---

**Explanation**
`numpy.core.defchararray` identifies where in the string it finds another string.  If it doesn't find it, it returns `-1`.  So I just need to check for `>= 0`.  I also take advantage of `numpy` broadcasting then check if any matches were found among all `keys`.

---

**Option 2**
I have a fondness for set logic.

```
df[df['Process Parameter'].str.split().apply(set) & set(keys)]

  Process Parameter  Value
1        System Clk    2.0
2          Core Clk    3.0
3    Bilinear Coeff    5.1
4        Prec Coeff    6.2
```

Comment: I've been waiting for you to answer!

Comment: I've been absolutely swamped.  I'll be swamped for a while with tiny amounts of time here and  there (-:

Comment: To complicate this further, in the list of keys, can I add another constraint that the strings should end with these keys. For instance, I want to match a partial string "Clock" but do not want to match "Clocks" ..... If the input strings are "System Clock", "Core Clock", "Clockspeed", the output of the regex match should only be "System Clock" & "Core Clock" –

Answer (score 2):

Use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `|` (regex `OR`) for boolean mask and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Process Parameter'].str.contains('|'.join(keys))]
print (df)
  Process Parameter  Value
1        System Clk    2.0
2          Core Clk    3.0
3    Bilinear Coeff    5.1
4        Prec Coeff    6.2
```

Detail:

```
print (df['Process Parameter'].str.contains('|'.join(keys)))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: Process Parameter, dtype: bool
```

Another solution with [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), what return `NaN`s for non match values, so [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) is necessary:

```
df = df[df['Process Parameter'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(keys)+')',expand=False).notnull()]
print (df)
  Process Parameter  Value
1      System Clk a    2.0
2        Core Clk a    3.0
3    Bilinear Coeff    5.1
4        Prec Coeff    6.2
```

**Timings**:

```
a = 'Temperature System Clk Core Clk Bilinear Coeff Prec Coeff Yield'.split()

N = 200000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Process Parameter': [np.random.choice(a, size=np.random.randint(1,10)) for x in range(N)]})
df['Process Parameter'] = df['Process Parameter'].str.join(' ')

keys =['Clk', 'Coeff']

In [115]: %timeit df[df['Process Parameter'].str.contains('|'.join(keys))]
10 loops, best of 3: 140 ms per loop

In [116]: %timeit df[df['Process Parameter'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(keys)+')',expand=False).notnull()]
1 loop, best of 3: 247 ms per loop
```

---

```
#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution 1
In [117]: %timeit df[df['Process Parameter'].str.findall('|'.join(keys)).astype(bool)]
10 loops, best of 3: 177 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution 2
In [118]: %timeit df[df['Process Parameter'].str.split(expand=True).isin(keys).any(1)]
1 loop, best of 3: 527 ms per loop
```

---

```
#piRSquared solution 1
In [136]: %timeit df[(find(df['Process Parameter'].values.astype(str)[:, None], keys) >= 0).any(1)]
1 loop, best of 3: 487 ms per loop

#piRSquared solution 2
In [137]: %timeit df[df['Process Parameter'].str.split().apply(set) & set(keys)]
1 loop, best of 3: 401 ms per loop
```

EDIT you need `word boundary` for matching:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Process Parameter' : ['Clockspeed', 'System Clk', 'Core Clk', 
                                        'Bilinear Coeff', 'Prec Coeff', 'Yield'], 
                                        'Value' : [1.2,2.0,3.0, 5.1, 6.2, 7.4]})

keys =['Clk', 'Coeff']
print (df)
  Process Parameter  Value
0        Clockspeed    1.2
1        System Clk    2.0
2          Core Clk    3.0
3    Bilinear Coeff    5.1
4        Prec Coeff    6.2
5             Yield    7.4

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in keys)
df = df[df['Process Parameter'].str.contains(pat)]
print (df)
  Process Parameter  Value
1        System Clk    2.0
2          Core Clk    3.0
3    Bilinear Coeff    5.1
4        Prec Coeff    6.2
```

Comment: This is an excellent approach! To complicate this further, in the list of keys, can I add another constraint that the strings should end with these keys. For instance, I want to match a partial string "Clock" but do not want to match "Clocks" ..... If the input strings are "System Clock", "Core Clock", "Clockspeed", the output of the regex match should only be "System Clock" & "Core Clock"

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
`str.findall`

```
df = df[df['Process Parameter'].str.findall('|'.join(keys)).astype(bool)]
df

  Process Parameter  Value
1        System Clk    2.0
2          Core Clk    3.0
3    Bilinear Coeff    5.1
4        Prec Coeff    6.2
```

---

**Option 2**
Just for fun, `str.split` + `df.isin`:

```
m = df['Process Parameter'].str.split(expand=True).isin(keys).any(1)
m

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool


df[m]

  Process Parameter  Value
1        System Clk    2.0
2          Core Clk    3.0
3    Bilinear Coeff    5.1
4        Prec Coeff    6.2
```

This method does not use regex based checking, however, it only works for single, full word matches (not multi-word or substring matches).

Comment: @jezrael Since it doesn't work for multiple words as you rightly said.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think a non-regex based comparison is faster than regex, but I can't guarantee that since I didn't time it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But I think here is better more general solution with checking more words keys - if OP not guaranteed always one word keywords.

Comment: I reordered the options, I hope it's okay now.

Comment: sure, then plus1 :)

Comment: Hmmm, second solution is slowiest, regex win ;)

Comment: I guess because more operations - split + isin + any

Comment: @jezrael, Thanks for timing it. That's disappointing, I would've thought that avoiding regex would speed it up but I guess pandas has optimised the regex functions very well.

Comment: Yes, I was surprised a bit too :)